# Why isn't this simple test class's method inherited in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Consider this very simple logging class:

```
class MockLog
  # ...
end
```

Let's add logging to all our classes:

```
class Module
  def has_logging()
    class_eval {
      @log = MockLog.new
      def log
        self.class.instance_variable_get :@log
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Now, why doesn't this work?

```
class Foo
  has_logging
end
Foo.new.log.nil?   # => false, as expected

class Bar < Foo
end
Bar.new.log.nil?   # => true?! Why wasn't the `log` method inherited?
```

Answer (score 1):

The log method was inherited (if it wasn't, you would get a NoMethodError), but your class level instance variable wasn't, so `instance_variable_get` returned nil.  You should declare a regular class variable like:

```
class Module
  def has_logging()
    class_eval {
      @@log = MockLog.new
      def log
        @@log
      end
    }
  end
end

class Foo
  has_logging
end

class Bar < Foo
end
```

Now it will be inherited.  See [Class and Instance Variables In Ruby](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)

Comment: Hmm.. but if the `log` method was inherited, then why does it return true when we ask if it's nil?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Now if you want to have a _different_ log in `Bar`, it can't override the `@@log` in `Foo`; they'll _all_ share the same `@@log` instance. I think the behavior he wants is "subclasses of `Foo` will use `@@log` unless overridden, but if they call `has_logging` themselves, then that subclass gets its own `@@log`".

Comment: That is, let's say you had `class Quux < Foo; has_logging; end`. I think the OP wants `Quux.new.log != Foo.new.log` to be true.

Comment: The continuing saga: Ruby's class variables friend or foe? (See here for some discussion: http://oreilly.com/ruby/excerpts/ruby-best-practices/worst-practices.html)